# MYSQL Rank based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, rank, window-functions, row-number

I am trying to create a query in mysql to assign row numbers based on multiple columns. Following is the format in which I need the desired results

```
    CN   PN  GroupName  WeekTimeReported    rank    desired_rank    

    X   ProjX   A       12/30/2013           1         1    
    X   ProjX   B       12/30/2013           2         1    
    X   ProjX   C       1/6/2014             3         2    
    X   ProjX   D       1/6/2014             4         2    
    Y   ProjY   A       1/13/2014            5         1    
    Y   ProjY   B       1/13/2014            6         1    
    Y   ProjY   C       1/20/2014            7         2    
    Y   ProjY   D       1/20/2014            8         2    
    Z   ProjZ   A       1/27/2014            9         1    
    Z   ProjZ   B       1/27/2014           10         1    
    Z   ProjZ   C       2/3/2014            11         2    
    Z   ProjZ   D       2/3/2014            12         2
```

I want my result in the desired_rank column format. So for Same CN and PN I want to rank based on the WeekTimeReported (I want to see the no of weeks project went for). Thank you for your help in advance.

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fcf037/1) and query:

```
SELECT 
 @cn:=ClientName ClientName
,ProjectName
,GroupName
,CAST(WeekTimeReported AS DATE) WeekTimeReported
,@rc:= CASE WHEN @cn=ClientName THEN @rc+1 ELSE 1 END AS rc
,desired_rank
,Hours
FROM sampledata , (select @rc:=0, @cn='') as rc
```

Comment: You don't say what your data looks like, or what you have tried for yourself. You will not get any help without those two steps being taken.

Comment: My apologies, I'm fairly new to the discussion environment of stackoverflow should have reviewed the guidelines. Please see the edited post. Thank you!

Comment: You could consider upgrading to MySQL 8 (now GA) which supports `window functions` - making this and similar needs so much easier to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider all the changes of data for the various columns.

---

This is what the query looks like in MySQL 8.0

```
select
*
, dense_rank() over(partition by `ClientName` order by `WeekTimeReported`,`ProjectName`) rnk
from sampledata
```

> ```
> ClientName | ProjectName | GroupName | WeekTimeReported | rank | desired_rank | Hours | rnk
> :--------- | :---------- | :-------- | :--------------- | ---: | -----------: | ----: | --:
> X          | ProjX       | A         | 2013-12-30       |    1 |            1 |     2 |   1
> X          | ProjX       | B         | 2013-12-30       |    2 |            1 |    10 |   1
> X          | ProjX       | C         | 2014-01-06       |    3 |            2 |     4 |   2
> X          | ProjX       | D         | 2014-01-06       |    4 |            2 |     2 |   2
> Y          | ProjY       | A         | 2014-01-13       |    5 |            1 |     3 |   1
> Y          | ProjY       | B         | 2014-01-13       |    6 |            1 |     1 |   1
> Y          | ProjY       | C         | 2014-01-20       |    7 |            2 |     6 |   2
> Y          | ProjY       | D         | 2014-01-20       |    8 |            2 |     1 |   2
> Z          | ProjZ       | A         | 2014-01-27       |    9 |            1 |     4 |   1
> Z          | ProjZ       | B         | 2014-01-27       |   10 |            1 |     1 |   1
> Z          | ProjZ       | C         | 2014-02-03       |   11 |            2 |    17 |   2
> Z          | ProjZ       | D         | 2014-02-03       |   12 |            2 |    16 |   2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b882e9d16d305c8c509a933f73294057)*

---

This is a partial answer for older MySQL, which I hope may assist you reaching the goal:

**Query 1**:

```
select
rc - rcwk
, d.*
from (
SELECT 
  @rcwk:= CASE WHEN @cnwk=concat(ClientName,WeekTimeReported) THEN @rcwk+1 ELSE 1 END AS rcwk
, @rc:= CASE WHEN @cn=ClientName THEN @rc+1 ELSE 1 END AS rc
, desired_rank
, ClientName
, ProjectName
, GroupName
, CAST(WeekTimeReported AS DATE) WeekTimeReported
, Hours
, @cn:=ClientName
, @cnwk:=concat(ClientName,WeekTimeReported) abc
FROM sampledata 
cross join (select @rc:=0,@rcwk:=0, @cn='',@cnwk='' ) as rc
order by ClientName, ProjectName, WeekTimeReported
  ) d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6abb82/1/0)**:

```
| rc - rcwk | rcwk | rc | desired_rank | ClientName | ProjectName | GroupName | WeekTimeReported | Hours | @cn:=ClientName |         abc |
|-----------|------|----|--------------|------------|-------------|-----------|------------------|-------|-----------------|-------------|
|         0 |    1 |  1 |            1 |          X |       ProjX |         A |       2013-12-30 |     2 |               X | X2013-12-30 |
|         0 |    2 |  2 |            1 |          X |       ProjX |         B |       2013-12-30 |    10 |               X | X2013-12-30 |
|         2 |    1 |  3 |            2 |          X |       ProjX |         C |       2014-01-06 |     4 |               X | X2014-01-06 |
|         2 |    2 |  4 |            2 |          X |       ProjX |         D |       2014-01-06 |     2 |               X | X2014-01-06 |
|         0 |    1 |  1 |            1 |          Y |       ProjY |         A |       2014-01-13 |     3 |               Y | Y2014-01-13 |
|         0 |    2 |  2 |            1 |          Y |       ProjY |         B |       2014-01-13 |     1 |               Y | Y2014-01-13 |
|         2 |    1 |  3 |            2 |          Y |       ProjY |         D |       2014-01-20 |     1 |               Y | Y2014-01-20 |
|         2 |    2 |  4 |            2 |          Y |       ProjY |         C |       2014-01-20 |     6 |               Y | Y2014-01-20 |
|         0 |    1 |  1 |            1 |          Z |       ProjZ |         A |       2014-01-27 |     4 |               Z | Z2014-01-27 |
|         0 |    2 |  2 |            1 |          Z |       ProjZ |         B |       2014-01-27 |     1 |               Z | Z2014-01-27 |
|         2 |    1 |  3 |            2 |          Z |       ProjZ |         C |       2014-02-03 |    17 |               Z | Z2014-02-03 |
|         2 |    2 |  4 |            2 |          Z |       ProjZ |         D |       2014-02-03 |    16 |               Z | Z2014-02-03 |
```